# Could not establish connection to "".The VS Code Server failed to start

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, raspberry-pi4, vscode-remote-ssh

I want to connect via ssh to the raspberry pi 4, but it doesn't work even if I enter the data correctly. I keep getting this error.I also tried Remote SSH: kill VS Code Server on Host and Remote-SSH: Uninstall VS Code Server from Host. Neither method worked.

[image]

Everything went perfectly until VSCode stopped working one day. I would be glad if you could somehow help me to solve this problem.

At the end, I receive the following message in the output:

```
> * Visual Studio Code Server
> *
> * By using the software, you agree to
> * the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-lice
> nse) and
> * the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacyst
[11:10:05.944] > 
> atement).
> *
> 
[11:10:05.964] > Server did not start successfully. Full server log at /home/pi/.vscode-serve
> r/.b7886d7461186a5eac768481578c1d7ca80e2d21.log >>>
> /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/b7886d7461186a5eac768481578c1d7ca80e2d21/bin/cod
[11:10:05.969] > 
> e-server: 12: /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/b7886d7461186a5eac768481578c1d7ca8
> 0e2d21/node: not found
> <<< End of server log
> 1b1d7bdad818: start
> exitCode==32==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==raspbian==
> arch==aarch64==
> tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime==14025==
> 1b1d7bdad818: end
[11:10:05.969] Received install output: 
exitCode==32==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==raspbian==
arch==aarch64==
tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime==14025==

[11:10:05.971] Resolver error: Error: The VS Code Server failed to start
    at m.ServerInstallError (c:\Users\x\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.98.0\out\extension.js:1:584322)
    at f (c:\Users\x\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.98.0\out\extension.js:1:578379)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\x\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.98.0\out\extension.js:1:581404)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\x\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.98.0\out\extension.js:1:681793)
    at async c:\Users\x\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.98.0\out\extension.js:1:644041
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\x\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.98.0\out\extension.js:1:647359)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\x\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.98.0\out\extension.js:1:645091)
    at async c:\Users\x\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.98.0\out\extension.js:1:720839
[11:10:05.977] ------




[11:10:06.331] > 
[11:10:07.263] "install" terminal command done
[11:10:07.264] Install terminal quit with output:
```

Comment: Can you "ping" that exact address or host name?

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by many reasons, the one that I encountered is,
**1st Problem and Solution**
The VM instance That you are using or particularly the volume that you are trying to access has full storage or no space is left on the device.

so go to your VM delete some files and try to access it again you should be able to access it.
[image]

**2nd problem and solution**
In your case, there are some node modules missing as we can see from the logs there is an issue in the installation of your pi installation
as mentioned in this file is missing. so try to install it again or try to find if you can locate this file and just put it in the right folder and then try to connect again it should work

```
/home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/b7886d7461186a5eac768481578c1d7ca8
> 0e2d21/node: not found
```